# Create a file to download without downloading to the server PHP

Tags: php, file, download

What I'm trying to do is to generate a file and specify the content in there without actually saving and creating the file on the server.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<?php
if(isset($_POST['download'])){
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=testing.txt');
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    echo 'Lorem Ipsum';
    exit();
}
echo 
'
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="submit" name="download" value="submit"/>
</form>
';
?>
```

The generated .txt file now contains content before `<?php` whic is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />` and also `Lorem Ipsum`, but I ONLY the want the content I specified which is just `Lorem Ipsum`

Comment: just move this line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />` after `if` or inside `echo`

Comment: but how do I specify the content I want to show, let's say if I only want to show the content stored in $content variable?

Answer (score 1):

Header should come before anything is echoed.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['download'])){
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=testing.txt');
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    echo 'Lorem Ipsum';
    exit();
}
echo 
'
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<form method="POST" action="index.php.php">
<input type="submit" name="download" value="submit"/>
</form>
';
?>
```

To keep it in the same structure:

```
$data = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />';

if(isset($_POST['download'])){
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=testing.txt');
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    echo 'Lorem Ipsum';
    exit();
}
$data .='
<form method="POST" action="index.php.php">
<input type="submit" name="download" value="submit"/>
</form>
';

echo $data;
```

Comment: instead of using this header method, is there anyway that i could do the same thing so I don't have to place the code before anything is echoed?

Comment: You could store all your site html and css in a variable and echo it out in the end?
I'll update my answer to show an example.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! anyway I've figured another way to do it, I will update my answer soon..

Answer (score 0):

I've created another file called `createfile.php`:

```
<?php
     header('Content-diposition: attachment; filename=testing.php');
     header('Content-type: text/plain');
     echo 'Lorem Ipsum';
?>
```

and in `index.php`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<form action="createfile.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

now it will only load things in createfile.php